# How to query user with results of match?

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
dport = t.cmd("show ift").to_enum(:scan, /eth-\d/).map { Regexp.last_match }
```

As a result, I get the following:

```
[#<MatchData "eth-0">, #<MatchData "eth-1">, #<MatchData "eth-2">, #<MatchData "eth-3">, #<MatchData "eth-4">, #<MatchData "eth-8">]
```

The good thing is that this is exactly what I'm shooting for; with respect to the matches. However, I'm a bit puzzled at how to move forward. I'd like to query the user and have the user select a particular match. Any ideas? Thank you in advance for any help in getting me going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you will first need to extract the matched strings from each MatchData object to present to the user with something like:

```
dport.each { |match| puts match[some_index] }
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html for more information on the MatchData object.

Then assuming your using the command line to get the input from the user use the gets() method: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-gets

Comment: Thanks for getting me going. This is what I ended up doing and it works like a champ.

`code
sel = 1
vport = t.cmd("show ift").scan(/eth-\d/)
vport.each { |p1, p2| 
  print "#{sel}) #{p1}#{p2}\n" 
  sel += sel
  }
`